# NodeJS - mysql connection exceptions not caught

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

I am new to Node.js and I have the following code below:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

async function insertNewRecord(record) {
      const connectionUrl = 'mysql://root:mypassword@mydatabasehost:3306/mydb';
      const pool = mysql.createPool(connectionUrl);
      pool.on('connection', function (conn) {
           console.log('*******on connection***********');
      });
      pool.on('error', function () {
          console.log('****POOL CONNECTION ERROR***');
      });
      await pool.query('INSERT INTO users SET ?', record);
}
async function doProcess() {
     try {
          //construct record object
          insertNewRecord(record)
     } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
     }
}
```

I purposely used the wrong database host name to see if the error would be caught and logged, but I saw no log. I was expecting to see **POOL CONNECTION ERROR** in the logs but it didn't show up. No error was caught either from the catch statement.

Am I doing something wrong? I did my own research and the `pool.on` lines you see in the codes is what I have tried to add, but doesn't seem to work. Am I doing error handling the correct way?

Answer (score 1):

`insertNewRecord(record)` is an asynchronous function. If you don't use `await` with it node won't wait for the function to complete, and you won't see the error.

Comment: tried placing await on the method call but this error showed up -> ''await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules.'

Comment: show us the code where you call `doProcess`. Also you have used event listeners which do not throw an error, so the `try-catch` wont be helpful if you are expecting to "catch" the error thrown by creating a connection.

Comment: i have fixed it. i just needed to put async in the forEach definition calling doProcess. Despite that, still no errors caught. maybe its in the mysql library?